# How to subtract dates in Oracle PL SQL

Tags: date, plsql

I'm using Oracle 18c.
I'm trying to determine elapsed time, but I get an error when I subtract two date variables in PL SQL.
The following code works fine:

```
DECLARE
    l_zero_date     date;
    l_current_date  date;
    l_elapsed_time  date;
BEGIN
    Execute Immediate 'ALTER SESSION set nls_timestamp_format = "DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS"';
    l_zero_date := to_date('01-01-1900 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
    dbms_output.put_line('The value of l_zero_date is: ' || l_zero_date);
    Select ls.duration Into l_current_date From LIT_STATS ls Where ls.prim_key = 1002;
    dbms_output.put_line('The value of l_curr_date is: ' || l_current_date);
--    dbms_output.put_line('The elapsed time is: ' || l_current_date - l_zero_date);

END;
```

This produces the results:

```
The value of l_zero_date is: 1900-01-01 00:00:00
The value of l_curr_date is: 1900-01-01 00:35:22
```

However, If I un-comment the last dbms_output line I get the error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 14
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

I don't understand why I get the error on subtraction involving two fields declared as DATE.  For example, the following code works fine:

```
declare
        a       date;
        b       date;
begin
        a := sysdate;
        dbms_lock.sleep(10);    -- sleep about 10 seconds give or take
        b := sysdate;
        dbms_output.put_line( b-a || ' of a day has elapsed' );
        dbms_output.put_line( (b-a)*24 || ' of an hour has elapsed' );
        dbms_output.put_line( (b-a)*24*60 || ' of a minute has elapsed' );
        dbms_output.put_line( (b-a)*24*60*60 || ' seconds has elapsed' );
end;
```

Why does the line `dbms_output.put_line('The elapsed time is: ' || l_current_date - l_zero_date);` produce an error?
Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: what is the datatype of LIT_STATS.duration ?

Comment: Hi Koen.  It's Date.

Comment: Wrap the dates in parentheses: `(l_current_date - l_zero_date)`.  It is an order of operations issue.  It is concatenating the date with the string before attempting the substraction.

Comment: How can a date be a duration?

Comment: Hi Del,  Thanks for solving this problem.  Wrapping the dates in parentheses did the trick.  I appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, this is an order of operations issue.  Take the following example:

```sql
SELECT 'TEST'||SYSDATE-SYSDATE FROM DUAL
```

When this runs, I get the following error: `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got DATE`

But when I wrap the dates in `(` and `)`:

```sql
SELECT 'TEST'||(SYSDATE-SYSDATE) FROM DUAL
```

The result is `TEST0`.

It is order of operations, the code moves left to right unless there are parentheses informing it to do the date subtraction first.

Here is a DBFiddle showing the queries being run ([LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3a5050c5250e8bfd55239d0ec3c835de))